# How to fix 'error pwsh: not available' in Neovim healthcheck?

Tags: neovim, powershell

I am on Windows 11. I do not understand what the issue is about or how can I fix it. I just know that 'pwsh' is not recognized as an excutable but I can execute powershell by running `powershell`.

Comment: I don't know about Neovim healthcheck, but perhaps you just need `:set shell=powershell`?